# Grails Domain class findBy returning different results for same param

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, grails, grails-orm

Ok we have a Grails domain(quasi-domain class some call it) class mapped to a view in SQL Server 2008.

Here is the view below:

```
    class DomainView {

    Integer someotherKey
    Integer someKey
    String firstName
    String lastName
    String otherName
    String address
    String city

    static mapping = {
        table name:"domain_view", schema:"sch", catalog: "cat"
        version false
    }
}
```

We are trying to do a basic SELECT off the view versus a key:

```
int some_key
```

However, we were getting inconsistent results.  I started debugging and I realized even within the same method, the exact same Grails dynamic findBy method was returning different results for the exact same key

```
DomainView dv = DomainView.findBySomeKey(key)

DomainView dv2 = DomainView.findBySomeKey(key)

DomainView dv3 = DomainView.findBySomeKey(key)

DomainView dv4 = DomainView.findBySomeKey(key)
```

Each findBy was returning different results.  Sometimes correct but usually the some_key value did not match the passed in param.

While the val of some_key was off for the returned item, the other_name or someother_key were always the same.

Example:

```
someother_key  some_key        other_name
        5301    1901        FIRMNAME    
        5301    2051        FIRMNAME    
        5301    2052        FIRMNAME    
        5301    2053        FIRMNAME
```

So we are doing a search for some_key = 1901.  We would get any of those four values randomly but only from the list where the other 2 values(someother_key, other_name) were the same.

Using findByAll also returns a single value which is randomly chosen from that group.  I assumed it would return a list, but it only returns a single item where the some_key may or may not match.

Comment: What is the datatype of `some_key` in table `domain_view`?

Comment: It is an integer value

Comment: the key variable passed to findBy is Integer too?

Comment: Yes an Integer key is being passed.

Comment: When using raw SQL in SQL Mgmt Studio and searching directly for somekey the correct single result is returned.